# Will a 3.8 GPA and 1 F with an explanation on transcript allow me to get into graduate school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, gpa, transcript-of-records

I am currently in my junior year, studying abroad in another country. The advisor at this school told me that I was enrolled in 5 businesses classes. I had asked her to drop one of them because I didn't need it and she said okay I will drop this course for you and you have 12 credits. I left her office and went on with my day and I came to find out later that she had not dropped my course and that I am still enrolled in 5 classes. The way the school works here is that you are unable to add/drop once that period is over.

Upset and frustrated, I went to her office and she said she can't remember what had happened because she has too many students. She had told me that I can either take the course or fail it and it won't affect my GPA. But on my transcripts it will say grade not available aka "F." I normally take 4 classes at home and I do want to enjoy my time here, so I don't know if I should take the "F" and explain what had happened to graduate school admissions office or just suffer and take the class that I don't need toward my major. It will not affect my GPA whatsoever if I were to take the F it will just be on my transcripts.

I trusted my advisor that she dropped my course, had I known that she wouldn't do it I would've done it myself. I do understand that I am at fault to for not checking it right after she'd done it, but by the time I found out it was too late. Thoughts?

Comment: What is your major? Business or something else?

Comment: Marketing & International Business, but I plan to go to graduate school in another department (Travel Industry Management).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having just gone through the applications process this year, on several of mine, there was a section that was designed for you to include any comments that didn't fit anywhere else. If you left them blank, that was fine, but I remember at least one saying something to the effect of, "if you have something that you want to explain, do it here." If there is no way to change it with your university, you can likely address it in your applications. Or, if you are really worried, you can take the class. I suppose it comes down to how comfortable you are with having that on your transcript.

Answer (score 3):

Don't overthink things -- these things happen, and the people who make the selection among graduate students know this as well. If the rest of your grades are good and you have a good explanation, then that's all that's necessary.